# Difference between Web Push and FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

First I have a bit of confusion between Web Push and FCM.

Can we implement Web Push without FCM or any other Cloud messaging service?

If so what is the difference between Web Push and FCM?

And is there any other Cloud messaging service similar to FCM.

Comment: FCM is just google's implementation of push notifications (not only webpush, but mobile apps also). There are many other providers, such as https://onesignal.com/. Apple has its own kindof web push system. You can't actually use FCM in Safari, and when you use it in mobile apps, those messages go through Apple Push Notification Services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Push is a browser technology based on [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API).

Firebase Cloud Messaging is a cross-platform messaging system. It works with Web Push, Android and iOS. It also uses Notifications API to show push messages in browser.

So if you want to use push notifications only in browser there is no difference in how they work, but FCM is easier to setup.

Answer (score 3):

**Web Push** is the technology. The term "web push" indicates a set of standards and related technologies, including the W3C Push API, the WebPush protocol, Notifications API, etc.

**FCM** is two different things:

- the **official browser push service for Chrome** (all notifications for Chrome are delivered through FCM servers)
- it is also a commercial push service that can send notifications to different browsers, like **Pushpad**, **OneSignal** and many others.

Comment: FCM sends push to Firefox without problems

Comment: @PavelBiryukov FCM is not the "push service" for Firefox. The "push service" (using the definition in the W3C standard) for Firefox is Mozilla Autopush. If FCM allows to reach Firefox is only in the role of a "proxy", just like Pushpad, OneSignal, etc. As I said the term "FCM" is used to refer to two different things.

Comment: I'm just confirming that FCM sends web push to Firefox (for free) - you don't need "commercial" service for that (which follows from your post).

Comment: @PavelBiryukov Maybe as a proxy, but not directly: FCM still needs to use the browser push service (e.g. Mozilla autopush in the case of Firefox, Apple push service in the case of Safari, etc.). The word  "commercial push service" does not refer to the current pricing (free vs paid) which can be subject to changes: it's just a name that I used to distinguish the two different things (i.e. the "official" browser push service VS the "commercial" browser push services that always need to use the "official" browser push service for deliveries).

Comment: In the case of Chrome, FCM acts as the "official" push service, and thus will be *always* free (since it's a standard browser API). In the case of other browsers (like Firefox), FCM acts as a "commercial" offering built upon the "official" push service and thus may be subject to a pricing as decided by Google (like any other service of Firebase or Google Cloud). The fact that they give it for free, it doesn't mean that this cannot change in their future pricing. That's the meaning of "commercial" compared to "official".

Comment: It's a strange discussion )) I'm not opposing you in any way - "commercial" just sounds you have to pay (my native language is c#, and of course everything free today can become paid) . We send pushes for many years - FCM, APNS, APNS through FCM, web, xmpp/upstream, proxy-direct etc - I know all this stuff. 3rd party maybe...

Comment: You can call it in any way :) but the only concept is that the term "FCM" is ambiguous and refers to two completely different things. Most people don't realize that and the difference is not always clear from FCM docs. One thing is using the Push API that returns an FCM endpoint and another thing is using FCM SDK which is part of Firebase suite (which is a "commercial" product, even if it has some things that are free).